# PHP's preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match

I am trying to get ONLY the numbers between the two brackets ([ ]) out of the string.

Here is my code:

```
$str = "[#123456] Some text";
preg_match('/^[#(?P<number>\w+)]/', $string, $matches);

// Returns 123456
echo $matches['number'];
```

Anyone able to help me out with this?

EDIT: I cleared up my question. I need to get ONLY the numbers between the brackets. The responses so far will give me numbers in the whole string.

Comment: Does it always start with a "#"?

Comment: Yes, it will always start with "[#" and always end with "]"

Comment: @Palladium beat me to it :P Use his :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the numbers as well as the braces around them, you can use this regex:

```
preg_match('/\[#\d+\]/U', $str, $matches);
echo $matches[0];
```

Otherwise, use

```
preg_match('/\[#(\d+)\]/U', $str, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

Comment: I've edited my question to be more clear. I need ONLY the numbers between the brackets.

Comment: @Draven The `\d+` matches one or more digits; the `U` after the closing delimiter uses non-greedy matching (in case you have more than one bracket set in one line).

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
preg_match('/[0-9]*/', $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

For more info on regular expressions, [click here](http://weblogtoolscollection.com/regex/regex.php/)

Answer (score 0):

Or...(edited for code to be displayed as code)

```
$str = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $str);
```

Comment: I've edited my question to be more clear. I need ONLY the numbers between the brackets

Answer (score 0):

This will return numbers only from within this context [#....]

```
$str = "[#123456] Some text";
preg_match('/\[#(\d+)\]/', $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
echo $matches[1]; // 123456
```